# Unable to launch safaridriver, getting error 'safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured correctly or you need to authenticate'

Tags: selenium, safaridriver

**OS:** macOS Sierra

**Selenium Version:** 3.7.1

**Browser**: Safari v11.0.3

---

**Problem**:
Cannot launch safaridriver even though 'Allow Remote Automation' is checked and safaridriver --enable has been run.

**Error**

'safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured
correctly or you need to authenticate. Re-run safaridriver(1) and
pass the '--enable' flag to configure and/or authenticate.
For more information, consult the safaridriver(1) man page.'

**Error Log**

```
$ selenium-standalone start -- -role node -nodeConfig nodes/safari.json
17:34:07.814 INFO - Selenium build info: version: '3.7.1', revision: '8a0099a'
17:34:07.815 INFO - Launching a Selenium Grid node
2018-02-21 17:34:08.104:INFO::main: Logging initialized @574ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
17:34:08.137 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
17:34:08.150 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities {browserName: internet explorer, ensureCleanSession: true, platform: WINDOWS, version: } does not match the current platform MAC
17:34:08.150 INFO - Driver provider class org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
 registration capabilities Capabilities {browserName: MicrosoftEdge, platform: WINDOWS, version: } does not match the current platform MAC
17:34:08.180 INFO - Using the passthrough mode handler
2018-02-21 17:34:08.198:INFO:osjs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.5.v20170502
2018-02-21 17:34:08.216:WARN:osjs.SecurityHandler:main: ServletContext@o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22fcf7ab{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: /
2018-02-21 17:34:08.219:INFO:osjsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@22fcf7ab{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2018-02-21 17:34:08.236:INFO:osjs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@77f80c04{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:5555}
2018-02-21 17:34:08.237:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @707ms
17:34:08.237 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
17:34:08.241 INFO - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
17:34:08.242 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://qa-docker02.avirat.net:4449/grid/register
17:34:08.256 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
Selenium started
2018-02-21 17:34:37.690:INFO:osjshC.ROOT:qtp2124643775-15: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet-2d3379b4: Initialising WebDriverServlet
17:34:37.705 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession@5064ed96
17:34:37.708 INFO - /session: Executing POST on /session (handler: BeginSession)
17:34:37.750 INFO - Capabilities are: Capabilities {browserName: safari}
17:34:37.752 INFO - Capabilities {browserName: safari} matched class org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession$Factory (provider: org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverService)
ERROR: safaridriver could not launch because it is not configured
correctly or you need to authenticate. Re-run safaridriver(1) and
pass the '--enable' flag to configure and/or authenticate.
For more information, consult the safaridriver(1) man page.
```

Comment: Have you tried passing the --enable flag?

Comment: Yes, I manually ran safaridriver --enable and entered the prompted password.

Comment: Did it work when you did that?

Comment: No, that's the first thing I tried.

Comment: Does anyone have some ideas to solve this problem?

Comment: were any of you able to get this to work? @allenwang